# Prove: $a | c$ and $b | c\implies ab | c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> For any natural numbers $a, b, c$, if $a | c$ and $b | c$ then $ab | c$.

Can this statement be proven or does it require a counterexample to disprove it?
I tried to prove it, but failed to get past any steps that I know of, so I think it is false.

Can someone confirm for me if this is false?

Comment: You can't prove it because it is false: Let $a=b=c>1$. Then $a|c$, $b|c$, but $ab\not| c$

Comment: Perhaps what they wanted you to show was that if $a \mid b$ and $b \mid c$ then $a \mid c$?

Comment: no, it says "if a | c and b | c then ab | c."

Comment: We need a and b to be coprime for this to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false. Counterexample: $a=b=c=2$

Comment: @Jzy96 All you have to say is that "the claim is not true because with $a=b=c=2$ we have that $a|c$ and $b|c$ but not $ab|c$"